# Find Area of shaded region.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

In the given figure $AB$ = $9cm$, $AD$ = $BC$ = $10cm$, $DB$ = $AC$ = $17cm$. If area of the shaded
region is ${m\over n}$, where ($m, n$) = $1$, then evaluate m + n . [image: figure given below]

My Work :-

Well initially I had ideas of joining $D$ and $C$ and then maybe using something related to similar triangles. Well then I had another idea of maybe finding the height of the trapezium $ABCD$ and then maybe find height of the shaded triangle and similar ones. However whenever I am approaching either ways, I am just getting stuck in variables.

So I need an advice as to how to approach this problem.

Comment: Please show the own effort to solve the problem, it is the way it works.

Comment: Extend AB on either sides by 6. Some right triangles will be obtained. Use similarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the picture for the situation:

[image: Stackexchange picture 3968678]

One possibility to "see the height" is as follows.

Of course, we have an isosceles trapezium $ABCD$.
In the triangle $\Delta ABC$ the sides are known, $9, 10, 17$, the semi-perimeter is $(9+10+17)/2=18$, so Heron gives its area $[ABC]=A_1+A_3$ as
$$
[ABC]=A_1+A_3=\sqrt{18(18-9)(18-10)(18-17)}=36\ .
$$
Since $AB=9$, the heights $DD'$ and $CC'$ of the isosceles trapezium have both length $8$. This gives then $AC'=BD'=15$, since there is the pythagorean triple $(8, 15, 17)$. We get $BC'=AD'=6$ finally. (And one can take this as a start).

Let us now denote by $A_1$ and $A_2$ the areas of the similar triangles $\Delta XAB$ and $\Delta XCD$. It is easy to compute all areas now. We may also want to compute the position of $X$, the intersection of the diagonals, on the diagonals:
$$
\begin{aligned}
A_1 + A_3 &= [ABC] = 36 \ ,\\
\frac {A_1}{A_3} &= \frac{XA}{XC} =\frac{AB}{CD}=\frac {9}{21}=\frac37\ ,\\
\frac {A_1}{A_1+A_3} &= \frac3{3+7}=\frac3{10}\ ,\\
A_1 &= (A_1+A_3)\cdot \frac3{10}=36\cdot  \frac3{10}=\frac{54}5\ . 
\end{aligned}
$$

$\square$

---

@Note: Checks, and other possibilities to get $A_1$:

The area $[ABCD]$ is $\frac 12\cdot 8(9+21)=120$, and $A_1=54/5$, $A_3=126/5$, $A_2=294/5$. We have

- $A_1+A_3=36$, as it should be $\frac 12\cdot 9\cdot 8$,
- $A_2+A_3=84$, as it should be $\frac 12\cdot 21\cdot 8$,
- $A_1:A_2=9/49=(3/7)^2=(9/21)^2=(AB/CD)^2$, as it should be from the similarity.
- $A_1+A_2+2A_3=[ABCD]=120$.

Comment: thnx @dan_fulea

Comment: In what program did you made that picture?

Comment: @Derik geogebra, the lengths of the segments are shown automatically if the label option is set, and set to point to the value. The text boxes, and the labels for the vertices may be set using LaTeX.

Answer (score 2):

[image: figure]

Let the intersection point of $AC,BD$ be denoted by $O$. Let $V$ be the point on $AB$ such that $OV\perp AB$. Since $\triangle DAB\cong\triangle CBA(SSS),\triangle AOB$ is isosceles and $AV=BV=4.5$.

Then $\tan\angle OAB=\frac{OV}{AV}$ which gives the required area $\Delta=OV\times AV=4.5^2\tan\angle OAB$.

Let $X$ be the point on $AC$ such that $BX\perp AC$. Then $BX^2=9^2-AX^2=10^2-(17-AX)^2$ giving $AX=\frac{135}{17}$.

Now, $\tan\angle OAB=\frac{BX}{AX}$. Can you complete?

> $\tan\angle OAB=0.5\bar3$ giving $\Delta=10.8=\frac{54}5.$

Comment: thnx @ShubhamJohri

Answer (score 0):

Given the triangle’s base $9$ and its rational area $\frac mn$, its height is rational; so are likely the height and the base of the triangle DAB per similar triangles. Note that $(8,15,17)$ and $(6,8,10)$ are Pythagorean’s triplets. It is determined that $8$ and $15$ fit its height and base, respectively, which leads to $\frac{\frac 92}{15}\cdot 8=\frac{12}{5}$ as the height of the shaded triangle. Thus, its area is $\frac12\cdot\frac{12}5\cdot 9=\frac{54}5 $.